# grav cms materilaize.css img caption in twig

Tags: twig, materialize, grav

I am using Grav Cms w/materilaize.css. For image capition I need the following html syntax in materialize:

```
<img class="materialboxed" 
     data-caption="A picture of a way with a group of trees in a park" 
     src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/nature/4"
>
```

In twig I use the following in general:

```
{{ image.html('', '', 'materialboxed responsive-img card') }}
```

But I do not know how can I add the `data-caption` element to this line?

Answer (score 0):

The best route would be to use the [`url`](https://learn.getgrav.org/content/media#url) function instead of `html`, as it provides more flexibility in modifying the actual element.

```
<img src="{{ image.src }}" 
  class="materialboxed responsive-img card" 
  data-caption="A picture of a way with a group of trees in a park"
>
```